# Isolating (separating) two users in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, user-profiles, administration

Title says it all --- my problem is that there are two users and one machine running Windows 10. My goal is to separate two administrator users to the extent that after you select one of user profiles and enter the system you can barely notice that there is another user account created.

For example, simply creating another user and giving it admin rights doesn't separate and isolate the memory on disks for the users: one can access the files and software of another user. If user A installs a program, user B will most likely see a new shortcut on its Desktop. If user B creates a document and stores it somewhere, user A can easily access it. So far, the separation goes only for settings and preferences, but that is not enough for me.

*What I tried so far:*

1. Since both users are admins, I tried to achieve file isolation by
   revoking the rights of another user to influence a specific folder
   (except for deletion --- user B can still permanently delete user
   A's folder or file);
2. Thought about installing a separate OS to
   the pre-allocated encrypted disk space, but decided to ask for your
   opinion first, because it is kind of a hustle in my current
   situation (although it is manageable).

Question: is there any proper way to do this kind of "surgery"?

Looking forward to your replies!

P.S. one thing I read at StackExchange is that people suggest logging in two online Microsoft accounts. By doing so you tell them to do a proper isolation of OS space automatically. But I **don't want to create any accounts at Microsoft**.

I have found some similar questions, but mostly about shared Desktop and admin rights. My question extends it further and I hope it would be useful for some people in the future.

Comment: It's not possible. One admin can see everything another admin does.

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you for your comment. What do you think would help me to fix my issue? Is there any other ways to do this without revoking other user's admin rights?

And what do you think about running two operating systems? Would that help me (or even be do-able)?

Comment: Admin A cannot see Admin B’s User folders without taking ownership. So if both parties are reasonable, you can share in some peace and use the same apps. Otherwise with a fast machine and a fast NVMe SSD drive then one Admin can use a Virtual Machine. This is a different machine with its own apps and separate Windows password. That is more isolated.

Comment: @John thank you for your comment. I am not quite sure what do you mean by saying "both parties are reasonable" and "can share in some peace". Are you suggesting that I could partly achieve what I am trying to do by setting folder's ownership by-hand? In this case would disk say `D:\ ` work? Or it just be specifically `C:\Users\Admin_A\ ` and so on?

Comment: User folders are very secure.  So what I mean was if users are just doing their work and not trying to take ownership of other users folders it should work. I allowed my colleague and friend to make changes to my work PC when I was not there. Nothing happened.  That is what I meant. We are both Admins in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin account has full permission on the PC, he can access to everywhere that he want, just need to take ownership or edit security permission.So your goal cannot be achieved in general.
My idea is using BitLocker or other encryption software to protect important personal data, then other admin can’t access to them.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Huh, I guess then that my question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

you can just install 2 almost identical Windows 10 Systems on one drive.
-MBR can function as a "GRUB-Bootloader"
-Take care of partitioning:
Masterbootrecord: -> Disk0, Volume0
Admin A => Win10 Pro -> Disk 0, Volume1, Partition C:
Admin B => Win10 Pro -> Disk 0, Volume2, Partition C:\

It is like having 2 Systems.
At booting into MBR, you can choose, into which OS you want to boot.
Note, that you only make the difference by the volume from that point, so remember your volume!

You can do this solution with as many isolated systems, as you want, but you need enough space!

Every Admin is isolated, because the whole system, he is operating on, is isolated.
Even the kernel are not neccesarly the same.
If from Admin A for example the kernel get hacked, the kernel from B is still save.

That is my best solution for now.

Answer (score -1):

The question doesn't really describe the use-case. Why do you want two isolated administrators exactly? What kind of hardware and resources are you working with? I don't know. But here are some suggestions anyway.

To answer your specific question: No. You cannot have two isolated administers administrating the same host environment. However, there are several ways you can achieve something similar.

The dope simple way (in theory):

Create an architecture similar to what you would use in linux.
Use a root administrator controlling two superusers. You then setup security policies on each superuser. You might not be able to prevent a user from seeing each other's applications (I'm not sure) but you can prevent them from executing specific applications. File directories are easy although ideally you'd use two separate hard drives for storage.

The complicated way:

Install a single VM on your host machine. This is your base image. You can reuse your host windows lisence in client machines. It qualifies as a [supplemental license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/images-eula)

Create a docker container for user A. Create a docker container for user B. Use the VM as the base image for both containers.

You've effectively created a virtual server. You can network your client machines however you want. They are two different computers with two different IP addresses.

Remember: Virtual machines emulate the hardware. Docker images emulate software.

Extra Detail:

Why the VM when you can simply run docker containers on the host? It consumes a lot fewer resources.

You are also creating a separation of concerns. You can recreate any one piece of the architecture without recreating the whole thing.

You want to create a new user? You already have a container with a default profile. You can change that profile whenever you want.

You need to reinstall Windows? The VM and the containers aren't effected.

Something goes wrong with the base image? Spin-up a backup without touching the host.

The list goes on...

Comment: Hello, the 1st paragraph shouldn't really be a part of an answer. If you're undure about something, you should be commenting. Overall this answer looks quite chaotic, please format it in a better way.